# Random every 4-5 frames. not every frame

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a school project where a 'player' is moving next to a wall. This wall is made of cubes (1x1x1). These cubes have cubes in them (0.9x0.9x0.9) which move outwards, towards the player when the player moves next to them.

This animation now moves every **1 frame**. which is kinda laggy and unnatural.

I would like this animation to move every **5 frames**.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class InteractiefBlokje : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform thePlayer;

    private Transform binnenBlokje;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // referentie naar binnenblokje
        binnenBlokje = this.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0);
        // referentie naar de 'player'
        thePlayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
        Debug.Log(thePlayer);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector3 myPosition = this.transform.position;
        Vector3 playerPosition = thePlayer.position;

        // afstand tussen player en dit blokje
        float distance = Mathf.Clamp(Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(myPosition.x, myPosition.z), new Vector2(playerPosition.x, playerPosition.z)), 0, 50);

        // bij afstand 3 -> x = 0.8
        // bij afstand 5 -> x = 0

        binnenBlokje.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(0, (distance - 5.0f) * -0.4f), this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: given frames are not constant, wanting every 5 frames seems, unnatural

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to count the frames, you can use a counter, such as :

```
int FrameCounter = 5;

void Update () {
    if (FrameCounter++ % 5 == 0)
    {
        // your animation goes there
    }
}
```

or

```
int FrameCounter = 5;

void Update () {
    if (FrameCounter++ >= 5)
    {
        FrameCounter = 1;
        // your animation goes there
    }
}
```

But since there is time differences between each frames (FPS can drop/increases), you might want to use the time.

```
float timeBetweenAnimations = 0.1f; //0.1 second, arbitrary value
float timer = timeBetweenAnimations;

void Update () {
    timer += Time.deltaTime; // increase the timer by the time elapsed since last frame

    if (timer >= timeBetweenAnimations)
    {
        timer = 0; // reset the timer to 0
        // your animation goes there
    }
}
```

Or, you can use that timer and a speed to define a distance (distance = speed * time)

```
float timer;
float speed = 2.0f; // arbitrary value of 2 units per seconds

void Update () {
    timer = Time.deltaTime; // set the timer by the time elapsed since last frame
    var direction = new Vector3(...); // the direction you want your object to move, replace the ... by the real vector you need
     theObjectToMove.transform.position = direction * speed * timer; // feel free to add a * randomValue to increase/decrease randomly that speed
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, this is really helpful!